# PHP Adding and Subtracting Time to a given timestamp

Tags: php

I get a timestamp from mysql like

```
2012-04-12 16:42:33
```

in PHP how can i subtract hours, or basically how can i change timezone (-3 hours)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use PHP's [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php). You can check out the [supported formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) and then create a new object:

```
$date=new DateTime("2012-04-12 16:42:33");
```

This object also supports changing timezones and other conversions. Setting a new timezone (from PHP manual):

```
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Chatham'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
strtotime('-3 hours', strtotime('2012-04-12 16:42:33'));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Changing timezones is technically a bit more tricky, since the way your timestamp is formatted, we don't know what timezone the original is in.  So, this code should suffice.

Comment: that code converts to Unix timestamp, what about printing back a human friendly version?

Comment: @Francesco, use PHP's `date()` to format it however you want:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$hours = 3;

$time_old = "2012-04-12 16:42:33";

$time_new = strtotime($time_old);

$time_new = $time_new - (60 * $hours);

date($time_new);
```

This will allow you to dynamically change the hours by changing `$hours`.

Comment: You're subtracting minutes, not seconds; you need another `60 *`. But, I would strongly suggest _not_ adding a manual subtraction of seconds because it ignores [daylight saving time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) where applicable. See [this comment](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#97025) for an example.